# Is there a function whose total variation is unbounded but its restricted variation (mesh converging to zero) is bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, bounded-variation

Suppose $f$ is a bounded function on $[a,b]$, its total variation is defined to be
$$
  \mathrm{Var}(f) = \sup_{\tau} \sum_{i=1}^{n} |f(x_{i})-f(x_{i-1})|.
$$
Furthermore, if $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, it can be proved that
 $$
  \mathrm{Var}(f) = \lim_{|\tau|\to 0}\sum_{i=1}^{n} |f(x_{i})-f(x_{i-1})|,
$$
where $|\tau|$ denotes the mesh of the partition $\tau$.

When $f$ is discontinuous, can anyone give a counterexample to the above equality, that is the total variation cannot always be calculated by letting the mesh approaching zero?

Comment: If the limit exists then it is equal to the total variation. I don't know if there is an example where the limits does not exist.

Comment: The question asked in the title is different that the one in the main formulation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To see that the limit and supremum in question might produce difference results define $f:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ as
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases} 0, &\text{ if } \ x \neq 1/2, \\
1, &\text{ if } \ x = 1/2. \end{cases}
$$
Clearly $\mathrm{Var}(f) = 2$, but any partition of $[0,1]$, with diameter however small,  will result in $0$ variance-sum unless it includes the point $1/2$ in the partition of $[0,1]$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this simple example.  But the limit here is mesh-dependent, how about mesh-independent  counterexample?  Is there such a function : (1)  for any mesh appproaching zero, its restricted variation exists. (2) But its true total variation is quite different from the restricted variaton in (1).

Comment: @C.Davide, if I understand you correctly, there cannot be a counterexample that is partition independent. This is because the $\sup$ itself is realized on a partition with diameter approaching to $0$. Indeed, notice that $\sup$ is a limit of some sequence of partitions. But for any partition of $[a,b]$ adding more points to it can only increase the variation-sum. Hence, WLOG, we may assume that the sequence of partitions realizing the $\sup$ has diameter converging to $0$. Thus, there is at least one sequence of partitions (meshes) with decaying diameter, that coincides with the $\sup$.